# RabbitMQ Queue with no subscribers

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

"Durable" and "persistent mode" appear to relate to reboots rather than relating to there being no subscribers to receive the message.

I'd like RabbitMQ to keep messages on the queue when there are no subscribers.  When a subscriber does come online, the message should be recieved by that subscriber.  Is this possible with RabbitMQ?

Code sample:

**Server:**

```
namespace RabbitEg
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string EXCHANGE_NAME = "helloworld";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionFactory cnFactory = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

            using (IConnection cn = cnFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channel = cn.CreateModel())
                {
                    //channel.ExchangeDelete(EXCHANGE_NAME);
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", true);
                    //channel.BasicReturn += new BasicReturnEventHandler(channel_BasicReturn);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        byte[] payLoad = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world _ " + i);
                        IBasicProperties channelProps = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                        channelProps.SetPersistent(true);

                        channel.BasicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, "routekey_helloworld", false, false, channelProps, payLoad);

                        Console.WriteLine("Sent Message " + i);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
namespace RabbitListener
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string EXCHANGE_NAME = "helloworld";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionFactory cnFactory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

            using (IConnection cn = cnFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (IModel channel = cn.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.ExchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "direct", true);

                    string queueName = channel.QueueDeclare("myQueue", true, false, false, null);
                    channel.QueueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "routekey_helloworld");

                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages");

                    QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

                    while (true)
                    {
                        BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the [AMQP Reference](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html) for an explanation of what `durable` and `persistent` mean.

Basically, *queues* are either `durable` or `non-durable`.  The former survive broker restarts, the latter do not.

Messages are published as either `transient` or `persistent`.  The idea is that `persistent` messages  on `durable` queues should also survive broker restarts.

So, to get what you want, you need to 1) declare the queue as `durable` and 2) publish the messages as `persistent`.  In addition, you may also want to enable *publisher confirms* on the channel; that way, you'll know when the broker has assumed responsibility for the message.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it still doesn't persist messages if there is no client listening.  Code sample attached to question.

Comment: Good code.  Two problems: 1) the server should *also* declare the queue; declaring it twice isn't a problem and it's good practice and 2) queueDeclare() gives you an anonymous non-durable queue; you want queueDeclare("myQueue", true, false, false, null).

Comment: Also, the way you edited the question makes it hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Point taken regarding the edit (updated accordingly).

I've tried specifying the queue as you indicated (code sample updated to prove it).  Still the same result for me though.

Comment: Ah got it... declaring the queue on the client clearly is too late because the messages are already on the queue.  Adding the same bit of QueueDeclare & QueueBind code to the Server code makes it work.  Thanks for your insight (much appreciated).

Comment: What about uniqueness of the consumers? Do we have here the same limitation as in JMS where you can't subscribe two durable subscribers with the same id? This is very useful if you have an active/active model.